# Implications of nested transactions in Firebase?

Tags: node.js, firebase

I am running a transaction to update an item that needs to be stored in two keys. To accomplish this, I have setup a nested transaction as follows, and it seems to run as expected:

```
firebaseOOO.child('relationships/main').child(accountID).child(friendAccountID).transaction(function(data) {
    data.prop = 'newval';
    firebaseOOO.child('relationships/main').child(friendAccountID).child(accountID).transaction(function(data) {
        return r;
    });
    return r;
});
```

Are there any gotchas or possible unexpected implications to this?  I am most worried about getting stuck in some sort of transaction loop under load, where each transaction cancels the other out forcing them both to restart, or similar.

Is there a better way of doing this?

I am using the NodeJS client.

Comment: Why not try multiple-location update? - https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably don't want to start another transaction from within the callback to the first one. There is no guarantee as to how many times the function for your first transaction  will run, particularly if there is a lot of contention at the location you are trying to update.

A better solution, which I believe you hit on in your other question, is to start the second transaction from the completion callback, after checking that the first one committed.

Comment: Nice solution, but that leaves the DB in inconsistent state. What if some one is reading the data while the first transaction ended but the second one have not completed yet...
Is there is any solution that adds transaction to the atomic function of updateChild function.